# Alternative solution for below SQL Query ,TableMasterID NOT IN take so much time

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

Need alternative solution for below SQL Query ,TableMasterID NOT IN take so much time, If i remove AND TableMasterID NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT  c.TableMasterID 
            FROM ComFinalDataBS  as C 
            WHERE C.ComFileID  IN 
                (SELECT Number FROM fn_SplitInt(@ComFileID,','))) text from below query then getting result in 20 seconds otherwise result getting arround 4 minus.

```
SELECT A.SubTitleId,TableMasterID from SubTitle  as A JOIN ComTableMaster as B ON a.SubTitle = b.TblName  AND TableMasterID NOT IN  (SELECT DISTINCT  c.TableMasterID 
FROM ComFinalDataBS  as C 
        WHERE C.ComFileID  IN 
            (SELECT Number FROM fn_SplitInt(@ComFileID,','))) AND B.TableMasterID IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT d.TableMasterID 
        FROM ComData as D 
        WHERE D.ComFileID  IN 
            (SELECT Number FROM fn_SplitInt(@ComFileID,',')))  ORDER BY A.MainTitleID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  A.SubTitleId ,
        TableMasterID
FROM    SubTitle AS A
        JOIN ComTableMaster AS B ON A.SubTitle = B.TblName
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                     FROM   ComFinalDataBS C
                     WHERE  TableMasterID = C.TableMasterID
                            AND C.ComFileID IN (
                            SELECT  Number
                            FROM    MEFCampus..fn_SplitInt(@ComFileID, ',') ) )
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                         FROM   ComData D
                         WHERE  TableMasterID = D.TableMasterID
                                AND D.ComFileID IN (
                                SELECT  Number
                                FROM    MEFCampus..fn_SplitInt(@ComFileID,
                                                          ',') ) )
        AND B.IsDeleted = 0
ORDER BY MainTitleID
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried storing the result from the fn_split_string() into an indexed temp-table first? It should help the Query Optimizer a lot.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Number
  INTO #ComFileID
  FROM dbo.fn_SplitInt(@ComFileID,',')

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX uq0_ComFileID ON #ComFileID (Number) WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100)

SELECT A.SubTitleId,TableMasterID 
  FROM SubTitle  as A 
  JOIN ComTableMaster as B 
    ON a.SubTitle = b.TblName  

/*
   AND B.TableMasterID NOT IN  (SELECT DISTINCT c.TableMasterID 
                                FROM ComFinalDataBS  as C 
                                JOIN #ComFileID CFI
                                  ON CFI.Number = C.ComFileID ) 
*/

   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                      FROM ComFinalDataBS  as C 
                      JOIN #ComFileID CFI
                        ON CFI.Number = C.ComFileID 
                     WHERE c.TableMasterID = B.TableMasterID )


/*
   AND B.TableMasterID IN (SELECT DISTINCT d.TableMasterID 
                             FROM ComData as D 
                            JOIN #ComFileID CFI
                              ON CFI.Number = D.ComFileID 
*/

  AND EXISTS ( SELECT *
                 FROM ComData as D 
                 JOIN #ComFileID CFI
                   ON CFI.Number = D.ComFileID 
                WHERE D.TableMasterID = B.TableMasterID )

ORDER BY A.MainTitleID
```